# Selenium does not find existing elements that can be found by the browser aba elements and by using js in console

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, automation

I'm trying to automate the bet365 casino, I know they have tools to block bots.

link :https://casino.bet365.com/Play/LiveRoulette

I can't handle anything that's inside the div class="app-container", at least by selenium. But I find these elements using JavaScript in the browser console.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as UChrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

UChrome.install(ChromeDriverManager().install())

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



driver = UChrome.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/')
```

after login

```
driver.get('https://casino.bet365.com/Play/LiveRoulette')

locator = (By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@class, "second-dozen")]')
```

I try
probably the selectors should be a little different

```
driver.execute_script('return document.getElementsByClassName("roulette-table-cell roulette-table-cell_side-first-dozen roulette-table-cell_group-dozen")[0].getBoundingClientRect()')
```

Try

```
driver.find_element(locator[0], locator[1])
```

but I recive this:     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//*[contains(text(), "PAR")])[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
Stacktrace:
0 0x55f8fa1bcee3

1 0x55f8f9c8a608

2 0x55f8f9cc0aa1

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing a delay / wait.
Redirecting to the inner page with

```py
driver.get('https://casino.bet365.com/Play/LiveRoulette')
```

It takes some time to make all the elements loaded there, you can not access elements immediately.
The recommended way to do that is to use to use Expected Conditions explicit waits, something like this:

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as UChrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

UChrome.install(ChromeDriverManager().install())

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = UChrome.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/')
#perform the login here
driver.get('https://casino.bet365.com/Play/LiveRoulette')

locator = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '//*[contains(@class, "second-dozen")]')))
```

I see you are also basically missing the `driver.find_element` method.
This:

```py
(By.XPATH,'//*[contains(@class, "second-dozen")]')
```

will not return a web element.
Also make sure that element is not inside the iframe.

Comment: Did you really create an account within _`https://www.bet365.com/#/HO/`_?

Comment: No, this is why I **suggested** according to the shown code the problem is with missing delay